# Schlick geometric attenuation function in shader producing incorrect results

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have been searching online for a while now on why my geometric attenuation term for my physically based shader (Which I posted a question about not too long ago) and I cannot seem to come up with a result. The function I'm trying to implement can be found here: http://blog.selfshadow.com/publications/s2013-shading-course/karis/s2013_pbs_epic_notes_v2.pdf

This is my current iteration of the function.

```
vec3 Gsub(vec3 v) // Sub Function of G
{
    float k = ((roughness + 1) * (roughness + 1)) / 8;
    float fdotv = dot(fNormal, v);
    return vec3((fdotv) / ((fdotv) * (1.0 - k) + k));
}
vec3 G(vec3 l, vec3 v, vec3 h) // Geometric Attenuation Term - Schlick Modified (k = a/2)
{
    return Gsub(l) * Gsub(v);
}
```

This is the current result of the above in my application:
[image]

You can clearly see the strange artifacts on the left side, which should not be present.

One of the things I thought was an issue was my normals. I believe this is the issue, because whenever I put the same function into the Disney BRDF editor (http://www.disneyanimation.com/technology/brdf.html) I get correct results. I believe it is the normals because whenever I view the normals in Disney's application, I get this.

[image: Disney BRDF Result]

These normals differ from my normals, which -should- be correct:

[image: In my application]

I use the same model in both applications, and the normals are stored inside the model file. Can anyone give any insight into this?

Additionally I'd like to mention that these are the operations done on my normals:

Vertex Shader

```
mat3 normalMatrix = mat3(transpose(inverse(ModelView)));
inputNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * vNormal);
```

Fragment Shader

```
fNormal = normalize(inputNormal);
```

P.S. Please excuse my rushy-code, I've been trying to get this to work for a while.

Comment: Can you give a link to the forumula you're trying to implement? I looked for the keywords, and what I came across all looked quite different from the code you have. I figure `roughness` is a float? You're mixing it with integer constants, which will work if one of the terms is a float, even though I personally think that code is clearer if it does not rely on these types of implicit type conversions. The `G` function does not use the `h` argument. Is that intentional?

Comment: On the normals: What you have **should** be correct. Calculating inverse matrices in the shader for each vertex would be highly inefficient, but I figure you care about correctness for now. I would write it as `transpose(inverse(mat3(ModelView)))`. If your transformation matrices are composed of only rotations, translations, and uniform scaling, it's enough to simply apply the rotation matrix to the normal. This whole inverse deal is only needed if you have things like non-uniform scaling or shear transformations in your transformations.

Comment: I am trying to implement this: http://blog.selfshadow.com/publications/s2013-shading-course/karis/s2013_pbs_epic_notes_v2.pdf Roughness is indeed a float and you are correct by saying I'm just trying to get it to work as intended right now.